# Anchors on the outer bounding box of a color bar

Tags: pgfplots

I have a `tikzpicture` with two `axis` environments in the horizontal direction:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [
            name=plotLeft,
            xtick={0,1},
            xlabel={$x$},
            ytick={0,1},
            ylabel={$y$},
            colorbar,
            view={0}{90},       
        ]
            \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {x+y};
        \end{axis}
        \begin{axis}
        [
            name=plotRight,
            at={($(plotLeft.outer east)+(25mm,0)$)},
            anchor=outer west,
            xtick={0,1},
            xlabel={$x$},
            ytick={0,1},
            ylabel={$y$},
            colorbar,
            view={0}{90}
        ]
            \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {2*(x+y)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The resulting picture looks like

[image]

For the alignment of the right `axis` environment, I used `at={($(plotLeft.outer east)+(25mm,0)$)},anchor=outer west` in the axis options, but what I would actually like to do is place the right figure with respect to the `outer east` anchor of the color bar of the left figure, if such an anchor is defined, and not with respect to the `plotLeft.outer east` anchor.

For an `axis` environment, all the anchors are defined in Section 4.19.1 of the `PGFplots` manual Revision 1.12 (2015/01/31), but I cannot seem to find such definitions for a color bar.

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A colorbar is itself an axis, so you can use the same anchors, you only need to be able to refer to such axis. The manual, in section 4.9.12 "Color Bars" (I have version 1.12.1, I hope this has not changed), says that the colorbar of the previous explicit `axis` environment can be accessed as `current colorbar axis`. However, if you  use its `outer east` anchor, the plots are not aligned vertically, since the colorbar does not have x tikcs or label. Instead, you can use the `right of south east` and `left of south west` anchors as in the following code.

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [
            name=plotLeft,
            xtick={0,1},
            xlabel={$x$},
            ytick={0,1},
            ylabel={$y$},
            colorbar,
            view={0}{90},       
        ]
            \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {x+y};
        \end{axis}
        \begin{axis}
        [
            name=plotRight,
            at=(current colorbar axis.right of south east),
            anchor=left of south west,
            xtick={0,1},
            xlabel={$x$},
            ytick={0,1},
            ylabel={$y$},
            colorbar,
            view={0}{90}
        ]
            \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {2*(x+y)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Nice! Btw, I just found out you can give a name to a `colorbar` by means of for instance `colorbar,colorbar style={name=colorBarPlotLeft}` in the options of the left `axis` environment. After that, you can use something like `at={($(colorBarPlotLeft.right of south east)+(5mm,0mm)$)}` in the options of the `axis` environment on the right for its positioning with respect to the `colorbar` of the left `axis` environment.

Comment: Yes, you can also to that to explicitly give a name to the colorbar. In any case if you want to add a manual shift to the second `axis` environment you can avoid the coordinate calculation (`($...$)` syntax) and write something like `at=(<axis name>.<anchor>)` with `xshift=5mm`.